# Does charset matter when I echo content from a BLOB field?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have various images in a mysql table (a classic BLOB field).

In my `viewImage.php` I simply do:

```
header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
//> Fetch Image from database then echo $row['blobField'];
```

Should I specify a charset ?
Should I write:

```
header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8' );
```

? For what I might I think, I believe the response is no we don't need to set a charset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, since character sets and encodings only matter for text.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to set a charset.
The `content-type` is to tell the browser how to handle a request. if you're sending `text/html` and `image/jpeg` then the browser will not be able to handle it.

It has to be one or the other, it can't be both.
Using `text/html` is kind of a catch-all.